# Repeated words in question content of the 2018 Developer Survey

Tags: bug, status-completed, survey-2018

It is a typo mistake. I have seen *but have* typed twice in the content of the 2018 Stack Overflow Annual Developer Survey:

[image: Screenshot of survey question with duplicated words highlighted]

Comment: It took me a while to find the typo without the Red Free Hand Circle. The Red Box just doesn't catch my attention in the same way ;)

Comment: Downvoted because I didn't know where to look

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Thanks for the heads up; this is now fixed.